# Can't load images from Content folder on iis in asp mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

In visual studio virtual server this works. But when I put site on IIS it doesn't display images from content folder.

```
    var imgPath = '/Content/Images/Icons/' + icon + '.png';
                var imageContent = '@Server.MapPath(Url.Content("-1"))';
                image = imageContent.replace('-1', imgPath);
```

I get errors in browser foreach image

```
http://localhost/Content/Images/Icons/carwash.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing is first,  are you sure that all of your 'icons' are part of the solution and are actually being deployed to your web server?  I have had a few instances where I would add a file to the solution directory and VS does not automatically include in it the solution, thus it never actually gets deployed...

If that is ok and the images are actually there, my next question would be, have you tried just using the `@Url.Content` helper in your view to determine if that is working as it should?

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Icons/SomeIcon.png")"/>
```

**EDIT**

Since you are trying to accomplish this in Javascript and the above  tag works in HTML, you should be able to condense that code up there to the following code:

```
var image = '@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Icons/")' + icon + '.png';
```

Go ahead and let MVC get the path to the Icon folder and append your file and extension to that. This should eliminate the need for string replacement and still be able to process the icon paths in JS.

`var image` will now be the complete relative path to the icon file you have passed to this function.  You can use this string to update and img src tag or create an image or whatever.

Comment: I use local IIS. I just change properties of project to use IIS instead of visual studio server so images are 100% there. I have tried that too but nothing.

Comment: Actually your code works if I use it like image in html. But I write this in javascript where I dynamically combine path with image file name.

Comment: Compare what JS is outputting from your function above and the source path that the HTML version is outputting for differences.